# Using %Matplotlib Widget, laggy interactive plots inside VSCode, unlike smooth rendering outside the IDE

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I'm facing an issue with interactive Matplotlib plots in VS Code and I was hoping someone could help me out.
I'm using the `%matplotlib widget` magic command, but the plots are choppy and  It's making it quite challenging to work on my projects effectively.

I've noticed that when I use %matplotlib qt, and the figure window opens outside the IDE, the performance is significantly better.

I've tried searching online for solutions, but haven't been able to find anything that addresses this specific problem.

1. restarted VS Code and checked for updates.
2. tried using a different plotting library (Seaborn).
3. adjusted the code to optimize performance (e.g., reducing data size).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)